# In Notes 9.0.1, how to show the ruler by default when a document is opened?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I don't seem to find a way to show the ruler when a document is opened in IBM Notes 9.0.1.
I'm using `@Command([ViewShowRuler])` in the `PostOpen` event but it's having no effect.
Putting the command in a button, or in, for example, `PostRecalc` works fine.

I've read in the Help that this command works in EditMode. The form opens in EditMode by default, but nevertheless, I tried this (in `PostOpen`) with no useful result:

`@Command([EditDocument]; "1");
@UpdateFormulaContext;
@Command([ViewShowRuler])`

Any idea or trick how to make this work?

P.S.: The same command when used in `PostOpen` in Notes 6.5 works well; as expected.

Comment: Tried to resolve this issue in various forms (agent calling, win32 API calls on doc open, etc). Nothing worked. Looks that Notes 9.0.1 renders the opening document in a wrong manner and the necessary formulas/scripts just don't work as expected.

Comment: I've also tried setting up a timer to open the ruler a second after the doc is opened, but, strangely, the Timer event isn't triggering!!

Comment: Since version 7 the Notes client was getting more and more buggy.
In version 9 there's a bunch of mess supporting RTL languages.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to put some code in the Entering event of the rich text field where I need/want the ruler to be used:

```
Sub Entering(Source As Field)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    uidoc.Ruler = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea!
But unfortunately, this doesn't work when the RT field has default focus.
The event still runs, but Notes is just being dumb.